# Call method WCF CORS by AJAX POST not working from localhost to other domain

Tags: ajax, json, wcf, post

I have WCF service with implemented CORS. I call by AJAX POST from localhost:59258 method in WCF. If I call this method by localhost on other PORT - it's working. If I call the same method the same WCF but another URL I get 400 Bad Reqest, see bellow. I tried to call method by Fiddler and it's working. Where can be a problem?

First example - **working** in AJAX and Fiddler

WCF with CORS listening on `http://localhost:8733/json/GetId`
I call from `http://localhost:59258` method GetId

Second example - **NOT working** in AJAX and **working** in Fiddler

WCF with CORS listening on `http://some.domain:8733/json/GetId`
I call from `http://localhost:59258` method GetId

Here is part of WCF interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
        UriTemplate = "GetId",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetId(string a);
```

Here is part of AJAX:

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://some.domain:15010/json/GetId",
data: JSON.stringify( {     a: "123" }),
error: function (e) {
    alert(e.responseText);
},
datatype: "json",
contentType: " text/json; charset=utf-8"
```

});

Log of fiddler - not worked example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days I found solutions.
Problem was on WCF service. I tried to use a lot of solutions on Internet. Many solutions concern WCF hosted on IIS. Only one solution for **SELF HOSTED WCF WITH CORS** which is working is here: [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/)